# What and where are the WordPress core-bundled scripts?

Tags: theme-development

I submitted a theme and they rejected the theme because: `Core-bundled scripts: Required to use core-bundled scripts rather than including their own version of that script. For example jQuery.`

Where exactly are these core-bundled scripts? I am not using jQuery but I am using Bootstrap, so I assume that is what they're referring to.

I've searched Google, but it returned nothing at all about the bundled scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see every script loaded by core in the [`script-loader.php` source file](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/script-loader.php). I don't see Bootstrap in there.